# Ionic 3 select tab ionViewDidEnter

Tags: tabs, ionic3

I have a "**TabsPage**" which is the first page of app. I use `this.tabs.select(3)` inside `ionViewDidEnter` of this page to select the 4th tab. This opens the 4th tab as the default tab but the div with class of `.scroll-content` doesn't have top margin so it goes up behind header. However if I use timeout like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.tabs.select(3);
}, 5000)
```

Everything seems okay when 4th tab is opened. What do you think the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your declaration of the type of life cycle event you are using. You declare the tab after the view has been created and I suspect there is a miscommunication between the firing of the tab select and the creation of the view itself ( that's why you are using a `setTimeout()` which is really hacky ) .

You can read up more on the life cycle events [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController) under the section ***Lifecycle events***

What you could try is to hit `ionViewWillEnter(){}` and set the tab without a timeout.

There is also a [tab input property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#input-properties) which you should be able to use in your tab tag.

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="3">
```

> selectedIndex (number)
>     The default selected tab index when first loaded. 
>    If a selected index isn't provided then it will use 0, the first tab.

Because the selected index is defined in the tabs components sitting in the view there should be no issues with view initialization of the tab.